# Project getting error after changing hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: hibernate

I put hibernate.cfg.xml file in src folder,every time i change any thing in hibernate.cfg.xml am getting project as crossed with red marks.
When i checked error log it saying i need to delete project/bin/hibernate.cfg.xml
After i delete it then project has no errors and i able to ran app.
Any Sugestions???

```
public class HibernateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    ///TODO Auto-generated method stub

    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Sasi");

      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
     configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
     StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
     SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

     System.out.println("Successfull");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem like hibernate issue, but a project build issue.

There is no much info in your question regarding your project IDE and build;

It is just a though but it seems you are editing your file while your webserver is running and the file under bin directory is in use. 
Therefore, when your IDE tries to compile your project it is not able to override the hibernate.cfg.xml under bin directory and you are having errors..
Again, it s a lot of guessing, but this is the scenario I thought of when I saw your question. your issue is not related to hibernate but to the project build.

Comment: OMG..ur just AWESOME...am closing eclipse and deleting that file and again opening eclipse and running..the probleam as u said am editing when server is ON..but why server is running am not running on server actually.... am just running main method but defalutly its running on server..

Comment: Glad it helped a bit, for your question I did not get how you are running your project, you are running a standalone class using Eclipse -> run as java app? If this is the case are you editing your file before class execution is terminated?

Comment: Oh its not a server ..i mean i saw red symbol in console i thought its only come for tomcat only.. yeah the execution not completed and its in red symbol... i got all ans thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the bin folder in your project and build the project again. It might help.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverFlow`. I believe that your answer should be a comment. Please review how you should post answers in the website. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer